# Retrieving number of rows with non-empty one-to-many relation

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, ebean

I am using Play Framework 2 (Java) together with Ebean. Among my model classes, I have `classA` with a one-to-many relation to `classB`. The associated table for `classB` therefore has a field which either contains `null`or an id for a `classA` entity.

I would like to retrieve the number of `classA` rows for which there are one or more associated `classB` entities. In SQL terms, what I want to do is this:

```
select count(id) from classA where id in (select classA_id from classB);
```

How do I do this with Play Framework / Ebean?

I am thinking that there should be a built-in method to perform this simple task instead of having to use raw SQL. Note that it is not viable to fetch a long list from the database and then count the number of entries in Java: I want to let the database do the work.

Comment: `select count(distinct a.id) from classA a join classB b on b.classA_id = a.id`

Comment: That's still raw SQL. How would you do that with Ebean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Query.html), they explain pretty well how to build the queries.

```
int count = 
   Ebean.find(classB.class)
     .fetch("id")
     .where("classA_id IS NOT NULL")
     .findRowCount();
```

In case you want the "distinct" result, add `.setDistinct(true)` to the query.

Comment: That's not a bad solution, and I can even reduce the amount of raw SQL by using the built-in `isNotNull()` to write `.where().isNotNull("classA")`. Only problem left now is that `.setDistinct()` (which I certainly need) doesn't work in Ebean (at least not in Play Framework 2.3.9): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472511/ebean-query-using-setdistinct-does-not-work

Comment: Is updating to Play Framework 2.4 an option? They state 2.4 would support newer versions of EBean.

Comment: Anyway, since this problem has now been reduced to another problem, namely that of `setDistinct()` not working, I will accept the answer.